# Sorting using sort delegate. i need to prioritize few numbers while sorting

Tags: c#

1. Object is having 100 members records with Name, ID, zip code parameters. 
   i have below zip codes in object. `10451,10452,10453,10454,10455,10456,10457,10458,10459,10460,10461,10462,10463,10464,10465,10466,10467,10468,10469,10470,10471,10472,10473,10474,10475.`
2. Need to object sort based on the zipcodes in below order.

it means,

```
10472,10455,10475 then
10451,10452,10453,10454,10456,10457,10458,10459,10460,10461,10462,10463,10464,10465,10466,10467,10468,10469,10470,10471,10473,10474.
```

3) can i use delegate or any other concept. please give some code.

Need object sorting based on multiple conditions.

```
Resultset.SearchResults.Sort(delegate(memSearchResult obj1, memSearchResult obj2) { return obj1.zipcode.CompareTo(obj2.zipcode); });
```

resultset- my complete result from db.
zipcode - comparing parameter.

Prioritize -  10472,10455,10475
then display other zip codes with name, Id.

Answer (score 1):

So, trying to extract the question, you want to order the objects as follows:

- First the ones with codes within a given list. Order them by the position of the codes in the list.
- Then all others, ordered by the codes in default order.

If yes, then this will work:

```
var prioritizedCodes = new [] { 10472, 10455, 10475 };

int GetZipCodePriority (int zipCode)
{
    var index = Array.IndexOf(prioritizedCodes, zipCode);
    return index == -1 ? prioritizedCodes.Length : index;

}

var orderedData = data.OrderBy(d => GetZipCodePriority(d.ZipCode)).ThenBy(d => d.ZipCode);
```

Generally speaking, chaining `ThenBy` calls should help you achieve any logic you want. You can read more about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.thenby?view=netframework-4.8).